# Imagick resize but don't save resized

Tags: imagemagick

I want to resize watermark.png but i dont want to chnage original watermark.png ! i want to get watermark.png and resize it and add on image.png but

I don't want to save resized file in watermark.png!

```
composite -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -dissolve 70% watermark.png image.png  image-watermarked.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have two images, both 400x250 like this:

background.png

[image]

watermark.png

[image]

Then you probably want something like this:

```
convert background.png \( watermark.png -resize 100x \) -gravity southeast -composite result.png
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see that the parentheses prevent the `-resize` from applying to the background.

If you want to use a dissolve, you can do that like this:

```
convert background.png \( watermark.png -resize 100x \) \
   -gravity southeast -define compose:args=20%          \
   -compose dissolve -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: but how to user dissolve here? i want an opacity for watermark.png

Comment: i used colorize  -colorize 50%

Comment: I have added information on how to dissolve as well.

Comment: Do you have an old version? Try `identify -version`. Anything older than around 6.9 needs updating. Current version is 7.0.

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 7.0.2-4 Q16 x86_64 2016-07-12 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lzma png tiff x xml zlib

Comment: Can you download my exact images and my exact command and try the last example and see if that works?

Comment: Are you on Windows or something?

Comment: Im using a gif image... thats becouse of it... how to solve it in gif animation?

Comment: Hmmm - it would help if your question accurately reflected what you are trying to do! What is animated - your background or your watermark? Can you share your background and watermark please?

Comment: wm : http://www.halliesawyer.com/wp-content/plugins/transparent-image-watermark-plugin/watermark-logo.png

Comment: convert bg.gif -coalesce -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 null:  \( wm.png -scale 30% \) -layers composite -layers optimize result.gif

Comment: i tried this its working : convert image.gif -coalesce -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 null:  \(watermark.png -scale 30% \) -define compose:args=50% \-compose dissolve -layers composite -layers optimize result.gif

Answer (score 0):

I found it ... ill make another resized image and delete it...

```
convert watermark.png -scale 30%  watermark2.png

composite -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -dissolve 70% watermark2.png image.png  image-watermarked.png

rm -rf ./man/tnx-v2.png
```

Answer (score 0):

another answer (this has -colorize for dissolve)

```
convert image.png \( watermark.png -scale 50%  -colorize 50% \) -gravity southeast -composite image-watermarked.png
```